# Upload Image to Firebase Storage without using a blob in React Native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am currently trying to upload a file to firebase storage without using a blob or trying to find another workaround to my problem.

In my managed React Native project I am using the expo-image-picker to select an image. Afterwards I am scaling the image down with expo-image-manipulator based on it's size (the exact implementation is not that important).

I am using `response.blob()` to get a blob, which I can upload to firebase, but the filesize on iOS is quadrupled. Therefore I am looking for another solution to upload images.

The picture is getting uploaded to the firebase storage like so:

```
const picture = "file:///file/path";
const randomId = uuidv4();
const response = await fetch(picture);
const blob = await response.blob();

const path = `images/${randomId}`;
const storage = getStorage();

const metadata = {
  contentType: "image/jpeg",
};
const imagesRef = ref(storage, path);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(imagesRef, blob, metadata);
// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on(
  "state_changed",
  (snapshot) => {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log("Upload: " + progress + "% ");
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case "paused":
        console.log("Upload is paused");
        break;
      case "running":
        console.log("Upload is running");
        break;
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(
      "Error uploading document (CreatePostDetailsScreen): ",
      error
    );
  },
  () => {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```

Any help is highly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able use Expo manipulateAsync() to get the base64 string of the image and upload to firebase with uploadString.

```
const getbase64 = async (image) => {
  const manipResult = await manipulateAsync(file.localUri, [], {
    compress: 0.2,
    format: SaveFormat.PNG,
    base64: true,
  });
  return manipResult.base64;
};
```

Then use...

```
const base64 = getbase64(image) /// function from above code block.

await uploadString(storageRef, base64, 'base64').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
});
```

You can use upload string to upload 'raw', 'base64', 'base64url' and "data_url" strings. It will default to raw if no string type is supplied.

I'm sure you've read them a million times, but here are the docs for uploading files as strings.

`https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string`

However, I'm not sure if you'll still face the issue of the file size being too large.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this I just set the quality on the iOs platform to be lower in the imagePicker itself and so far it is faster and I don't see any issues with the images themselves.

```
 const galleryImage = await launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            // aspect: [16, 9],
            quality: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0.3 : 0.6,
            videoMaxDuration: 120,
        })
```